# How to create Event Handler for my Class

Tags: c#, .net

I have following class

```
public class ButtonChange
{
   private int _buttonState;
   public void  SetButtonState(int state)
   {
            _buttonState = state;
   }
}
```

I want to fire an event whenever `_buttonState` value changes, finaly I want to define an event handler in `ButtonChange`

Will you guys help me please??

P.S : I dont want to use **INotifyPropertyChanged**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
public class ButtonChange
{
   // Starting off with an empty handler avoids pesky null checks
   public event EventHandler StateChanged = delegate {};

   private int _buttonState;

   // Do you really want a setter method instead of a property?
   public void SetButtonState(int state)
   {
       if (_buttonState == state)
       {
           return;
       }
       _buttonState = state;
       StateChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

If you wanted the `StateChanged` event handler to know the new state, you could derive your own class from `EventArgs`, e.g. `ButtonStateEventArgs` and then use an event type of `EventHandler<ButtonStateEventArgs>`.

Note that this implementation doesn't try to be thread-safe.

Comment: Nice way to avoid them pesky null checks. Did not think of doing that. Don't know why. Probably automatic robotic habits.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, for StateChanged event I havent assigned any empty handler but still it worked, is it necessary do that, could you explain me bit more about it??

Comment: If you don't have the "= delegate{}" bit in there, then if no-one subscribes to the event but you try to raise it anyway, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 1):

Property based event raising:

```
public class ButtonChange
{
    private int _buttonState;
    public int ButtonState
    {
        get { return _buttonState; }
        set 
        {
            if (_buttonState == value)
                return;
            _buttonState = value; 
            OnButtonStateChanged();

        }
    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonStateChanged;
    private void OnButtonStateChanged()
    {
        if (this.ButtonStateChanged != null)
            this.ButtonStateChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Help yourself with google "c# events msdn"

[Events tutorial (C#) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) if you are using plain c#. INotifyPropertyChanged is for WPF - you don't need it for POCO/simple type events

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is not just for WPF, it is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed (from MSDN) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: technically it can be used.. however it is a cornerstone of WPF Data Binding; personally i've not heard of this interface before WPF came onto the scene.