# C# Drop an item from a list if the item raise an event

Tags: c#, events

Here's what I have now:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string status;

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // do something and make change to this.status;
    }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public List<MyClass> MyClassLst;

    private void DetectChangeInList()
    {
        // if the status property of an item in this.MyClassLst changed, remove this item from list
    }
}
```

I have a `List<MyClass>`, and each of the `MyClass` will do some work and change the property `status`. I want to detect if any of the `MyClass` has its `status` changed and remove this item from `MyClassLst`.

I read about something on event but not very clearly about how to make it work.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885437/creating-a-custom-event and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086091/how-to-create-event-handler-for-my-class

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be notified about changes to individual properties of each `MyClass` instance, it's not something that can magically happen.

Your `MyClass` will have to be responsible for firing an event whenever something changes (usually the [`PropertyChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), i.e. the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface), and the other class will have to attach a handler to each item in the list to get notified.

C#6 has a couple of syntactic improvements which simplify this a bit, but you still have lots of work to do for each property:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // this is the event which gets fired
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // you need to raise the event in each property's setter
    private _someValue;
    public string SomeValue
    {
        get { return _someValue; }
        set { if (value != _someValue) { _someValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    private _anotherVal;
    public string AnotherValue
    {
        get { return _anotherVal; }
        set { if (value != _anotherVal) { _anotherVal = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }
}
```

In your case, it would be:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Never use public fields! 
    // Status should be a property which gets and sets
    // the actual private backing field (_status).

    private _status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { if (value != _status) { _status = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    }
}
```

You will also most likely want to change `List<MyClass>` into your own implementation of `ICollection<T>` which will attach and detach these handlers as you add or remove items. It is usually done by deriving from [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx) and overriding relevant methods. If you are not comfortable with that, a slightly simpler approach might be to make the list private and expose `Add`/`Remove` and similar methods where you will attach/detach to the `PropertyChanged` event.